# How to make Dropdown List with checkboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do we make a drop down list with checkboxes? C# lang is preferred for this.

Comment: take a look at http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/

Comment: Why is everyone voting this down? It's a good question with several valid answers.

Comment: Thanks Goran.. I got what i wanted.

Comment: If you got what you wanted, can you post the answer or accept one of the answers already posted.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Not a real one anyway, but you can fake one by making a scrolling div which appears when you click a button (using JQuery):

```
<div id="cbListDiv" style="height: 172px; width:300px; overflow-y:scroll; border:1px solid silver; margin-top:8px;">
<asp:CheckBoxList id="cbList" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" />
 </div>
```

Then you'd need to add some code to display or expand that region when you click a link on the page. That's about as close as you can get I think.